# Documentation for OpenCV CUDA

Tags: opencv

I'm looking for recent documentation on using OpenCV with CUDA, i.e. something similar to this example:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d3d/tutorial_gpu_basics_similarity.html

This page and the doxygen pages it refers to are wildly out of date. There's no cv::cuda::Filter, there's not even a opencv2/core/cudafilters.hpp anymore:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/dc/d66/group__cudafilters.html

None of these functions exist in the current 4.8.0 source. Where is the *real* documentation for opencv? Is this a "we regenerate the doxygen every day so its up to date :^)" type scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Folks, do not fall for this.

There are two source trees involved if you are building OpenCV with CUDA. The "main" opencv source tree, and opencv_contrib which contains cudaimgproc cudafilters, and other "modules". Between the two, there are identically named, identically namespaced functions, and very similarly named .hpp headers. It is very easy to look at just the main tree and assume things were moved around and thus the 'the documentation must be out of date!'

E.g. it will look very convincingly like opencv2/cudafilters.hpp has been replaced by opencv2/cuda/filters.hpp. They are different files...

There is both a cv::cvtColor and a cv::cuda::cvtColor, they have identical args and will give you deeply misleading errors if interchanged. If you followed a tutorial that did "using namespace cv; using namespace cuda;" at the top, this difference will be virtually invisible to you.

Comment: `cv::cvtColor` isn't meant to engage any cuda at all. I don't see the issue. `cv::cuda::cvtColor()` uses the import `<opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp>` and I can't find any indication of `<opencv2/cuda/*>` imports at all.